# How might one deal with a run-away job, short of "force quitting"?

Tags: evaluation, system

I've done some miscoding, and I'm in a loop that's producing output quite rapidly. So, it seems that I can't really get the Abort Evaluation or Quit Kernel options to "take". Of course, I can Force Quit Mathematica, but there's a little coding that I would then lose.

Well, I've probably dug a hole for myself here, and can't get out.

The particular coding in question is rather minor, so it's no "big deal". But I thought it might (or not) be a question worth asking.

I guess it's not productive to keep clicking on Evaluation.

Also, I guess too that's it's a truism that one should always/constantly  save things.

P. S. I'm running macOS Catalina Version10.15.4

Comment: This happens to me too. On windows you can go to task manager and delete the kernel but not the notebook. This will leave your code edits in the notebook. However, this does depend on your version of windows and mathematica. I think this is more something to try rather than a guaranteed approach.

Comment: Additionally, if you're sure you have a higher risk of doing a runaway calculation, it makes sense to use things like `TimeConstrained[]` or `MemoryConstrained[]` in advance.